# Integrating a delta function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

I'm trying to express a flux $F$ in terms of frequency $\nu$ using:

$$F=\frac{2 \pi}{D^2}\frac{a_0}{\sqrt{a_1\nu}}B^\frac{3}{2}Q\int p^2 dp \int r^2 (\frac{p}{mc})^2p^{-4}dr\;\delta\left[\frac{p}{mc}-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}}\right]   $$

Where $p$ is momentum, $r$ is distance from the centre of a sphere, $B$ is the magnetic field, $m$ is mass and $c$ is light speed, $a_0$ is a constant with units W Hz$^{-1}$ T $^{-2}$ and $a_1$ a constant with units Hz T$^{-1}$.

Dealing with the $p$'s first

$$F=\frac{2 \pi}{D^2}\frac{a_0}{\sqrt{a_1\nu}}B^\frac{3}{2}Q\int  dp \int r^2 (\frac{1}{mc})^2dr\;\delta\left[\frac{p}{mc}-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}}\right]   $$

The integral over $r$, which contains a Dirac delta function:

$$\int r^2 (\frac{1}{mc})^2dr\;\delta\left[\frac{p}{mc}-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}}\right] $$

Leads to

$$F=\frac{2 \pi}{D^2}\frac{a_0}{\sqrt{a_1\nu}}B^\frac{3}{2}Q\frac{r(s)^3-r(a)^3}{3}  \int  (\frac{1}{mc})^2dp \;\delta\left[\frac{p}{mc}-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}}\right]  $$

Where we've integrated $r$ between $s$ and $a$.

The other integral is

$$\int  (\frac{1}{mc})^2dp \;\delta\left[\frac{p}{mc}-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}}\right]$$

and is between some initial momentum $p_0$ and a maximum momentum $p_{max}$.
How would I deal with the integral over $p$ whilst also expressing the entire equation in terms of $\nu$?

Comment: You've got a units problem here: $\sqrt{\nu/B}$ isn't dimensionless.

Comment: I'll edit the post and enter in the equation in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of dimensionality problem by changing the variable to $x=\frac{p}{mc}$ one gets:
$$F=\frac{r^3}{3}\int p^2 dp\;\delta\left[\frac{p}{mc}-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}}\right]=\frac{r^3m^3 c^3}{3}\int x^2 dx\;\delta\left[x-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}}\right]=\frac{r^3m^3 c^3}{3} \left|\frac{\nu}{B}\right|.$$
Which is being the consequence of [Dirac delta translation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation):
$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }f(x)\delta (x-X)\,dt=f(X).$$

Answer (score 1):

First, you make a change of variables:
$$u = \frac{p}{mc}-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}},\qquad dp = mc\,du\ .$$
With this, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{r^3}{3}\int p^2 dp\,\delta\left[\frac{p}{mc}-\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{B}}\right] ={}&\frac{m^3c^3r^3}{3}\int \left(u+\sqrt\frac{\nu}{B}\right)^2 du\,\delta\left[u\right]\\
={}&\frac{m^3c^3r^3}{3}\frac{\nu}{B}\ .
\end{align}
That being said, as a remark from a mathematician, one should be aware that the Dirac delta is in fact a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), and one should be careful when treating it as if it were a function.

Comment: I think you should square the square root.

Comment: @Andrei Right, thanks.